# How to clear local state after dispatching a success action in redux saga?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

Im trying to clear my component state after a successful call in redux saga. How do I do it?

Im trying to use the component state for my input value

```
this.state = {
    department: '',
};
```

My current solution looks like this;

```
add(department).then(action => {
    if(action.type.endsWith('SUCCESS')) {
       this.setState({department: ''})
    }
})
```

Im trying to clear my input after a success call in saga.

Comment: Typically you'd have the value be in the redux store and consumed by your component via props. The saga can then handle updating this value. Is there a reason you want to have `department` be in the component's local state rather than in the redux store?

Comment: I dont really like putting all my states in the redux store. Especially states for inputs like this that will only be use one time. I rather use the local state for this. I've already tried that but Im thinking what if I have several forms using the same field, that would flood my redux store with same states.

Comment: If `department` is a local state, why bother dispatching an action to redux-saga? Sagas purpose is to make sure side effects are properly managed when an action is dispatched that will affect the store.

Answer (score 0):

The approach i usually take with this is to have the saga update a value in the redux store, and have the component check for that change. This may include running some code in componentDidUpdate.

If you'd like to avoid adding things to the store, i can think of another possibility, albeit a bit of a combersome one: you could create a promise and pass its resolve and reject methods as part of the action you dispatch. Then in the saga, it could call those to resolve the promise. For example:

```
export function* addDepartment(action) {
  const { department, resolve, reject } = action;
  try {
    // do something async with department
    resolve();
  } catch (ex) {
    reject(ex);
  }
}
```

To be used in the component's mapDispatchToProps like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  add: (department) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'ADD', department, resolve, reject });
    });
  }
});
```

... and in the component proper like this:

```
this.props.add('some department')
  .then(() => this.setState({ department: '' })
  .catch((err) => console.log('an error occurred', err));
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Will try this in a minute.